# One code to generate 500 Random numbers and then, the Nth smallest

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I'm able to generate 500 Random Number b/w (100-1000) and Nth smallest number in separate codes but, not able follow the right logic do both in one code and execute result in this sequence -----> 500 Random numbers and  then, the Nth smallest number from the 500 Random numbers generated.

```
package SortNthDc;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomNumbers {

          public static void main(String[] args) {

          Random rnum = new Random();
          int counter;
          int largest = numbers[0];
          int smallest = numbers[0];
          for (counter = 100; counter <= 500; counter++) {
          System.out.println(rnum.nextInt(1000));
           {
             for(int i = 1;  i<numbers.length; i++) {

                if(numbers[i]>largest) {
                     largest = numbers[i];
                 }
                 else if(numbers[i]<smallest) {
                     smallest = numbers[i];
                 }
          }
           System.out.println("List of array is: " + Arrays.toString(numbers));
           System.out.println("Largest numbers is : " +largest);
           System.out.println("Smallest number is : " +smallest);
        }
     }
  }
}         

Get this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
    numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
    numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
    numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
    numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
    numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
    numbers cannot be resolved to a variable
    numbers cannot be resolved to a variable

    at SortNthDc.RandomNumbers.main(RandomNumbers.java:11)
```

Comment: You have not declared `numbers` array

Comment: No, you have not even declared this variable.

Comment: after int counter; I declared int[] numbers = null; and I still get error message "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at SortNthDc.RandomNumbers.main(RandomNumbers.java:12)"

Comment: What you need is a good java book : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305377/can-anybody-give-some-good-books-to-a-java-programming-beginner-especially-for

Answer (score 1):

This is how it should be:

```
      Random rnum = new Random();
      int counter;
      int[] numbers = new int[ 500 ]; // you want 500 numbers ; so size should reflect that.
      numbers[0] = rnum.nextInt(1000); // Init First number
      int largest = numbers[0]; //Set it as largest
      int smallest = numbers[0]; // Set it as smallest
      for (counter = 1 ; counter <  500; counter++) 
      {
          numbers[counter ] = rnum.nextInt(1000); //Store numbers;
          largest = Math.max( largest , numbers[counter ] ); //Compare with previous largest
          smallest = Math.min( smallest , numbers[counter ] );  //Compare with previous smallest

      }
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat Sorry My bad, Have spent too much time with `i`'s ; Changed to `counter`.

Comment: Cool, I would have stuck with `i`, but I am lazy.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the declaration of variable 'numbers'. may be this his the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this :

```
int start = 100;
        int end = 1001;
        int counter = 500;

        int smallest;
        int greatest;
        int randomInt ;

        int numbers [] = new int[counter];
        Random random = new Random(); 

        randomInt = random.nextInt(end-start) + start;
        numbers [0] = randomInt;

        smallest = randomInt;
        greatest = randomInt;


        System.out.println("0th Greatest : " + greatest + "\n");
        System.out.println("0th Smallest : " + smallest + "\n");

        for(int i=1;i<counter;i++) {

            numbers[i] = random.nextInt(end-start) + start;

            smallest = Math.min(smallest,numbers[i]);
            greatest = Math.max(greatest,numbers[i]);

            System.out.println("Random numbers: " + Arrays.toString(numbers) + "\n\n");
            System.out.println(i + "th Greatest : " + greatest + "\n");
            System.out.println(i + "th Smallest : " + smallest + "\n");

        }
```

This may not print the whole log , from 0 to 499th number as it's too much to print. You can change counter variable to 20 or so to verify that it does print the whole thing